# How to handle multiple tabs using in firebase using realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a multiplayer game website. I am using three features of firebase.

- Firebase authentication
- Firestore
- Real time database

The data which is permanent is stored in firestore. Like profile image, username etc. The data in firestore is stored in collection `users` and the key is same as the authentication id which we get from `user.uid`

The second data is temporary data which contains the chat messages and current game situation and player turn etc. This data is stored in real time database.

There are two base objects in real time data base. One is `rooms` and other is `users`. When a user logs in to website the permanent data is taken from the firestore and placed with temporary data(because we might need to display the permanent data again and again). The function I am using to get permanent data and create combination with temp data is

//'uid' is the permanent `id` which is used in `firestore` and also in authentication.

```
export const addUser = async (uid: string) => {
   //gets the permanent data from firestore
   const data = await getUserData(uid);

   //Set it to realtime database my adding one more temp prop
   return await dbUsers.child(uid).set({...data, messages: []});
};
```

Till now everything is fine problem comes when I have to remove the user on disconnection. I used t

```
export const removeUser = async (uid: string) => {
   return await dbUsers.child(uid).remove();
};
```

The above way doesn't work for multiple tabs. Consider if user had opened multiple tabs and he just closed one server then realtime database will consider it logged out.

Do I need to create realtime data on the basis of another id using `push()` method. Kindly guide me to correct path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you're trying to track the user's online status using Firebase's `onDisconnect` handlers. To do this:

2. You write a value for the user's `UID` when they connect.
3. You then delete that value using an `onDisconnect` handler.

This indeed will not work when the user opens the app in multiple locations (tabs, browsers, or devices). The reason is that a user can be online in multiple locations, and your code and data structure needs to cater for this.

The idiomatic approach is the one outlined in the [sample presence app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-sample) in the Firebase documentation, and works with a data structure like this:

```
"OnlineUsers": {
  "uidOfUser1": {
    "-LKeyOfConnection1": true,
    "-LKeyOfConnection2": true
  },
  "uidOfUser2": {
    "-LKeyOfConnection3": true,
    "-LKeyOfConnection4": true
  }
}
```

In this structure, if a user has two open connections (on different tabs, browsers, devices), they have two nodes under their UID, each with its own `onDisconnect` handler. When both connections are closed, with connection keys disappear, and thus their `/OnlineUsers/$uid` node also disappears automatically.

So to detect if a user is online in the above structure, you'd check if there is a node under `/OnlineUsers` with their UID.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I needed. One more question. Is there any way to call some function when user disconnects.

Comment: If you want to execute some code in your app when it disconnects from the server, you can listen to `.info/connected` and execute that code when it becomes `false`. But note that this is unlikely to run when there's a clean disconnect, such as when the app crashes or when the user force closes it.